# SwiftUI NavigationView with in-window blending on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I'm trying to build UI similar to Maps.app in SwiftUI for macOS. I'm having trouble to apply [in-window blending mode](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/visual-design/translucency/) for toolbar and sidebar. The code for the app is roughly this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(...)

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Sidebar()
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
        }
        .navigationTitle("New York, NY")
    }
}
```

For reference, here's the screenshot from Maps.app. It might be difficult to see but Map component is visible through the translucent toolbar and sidebar:

[image: Maps.app on macOS]

With the code above in place, i get the following result (modified from [github.com/jordansinger/maps-macos-swiftui-sample](https://github.com/jordansinger/maps-macos-swiftui-sample)). Note that the toolbar is plain white and sidebar uses behind-window blending mode:

[image: Map component with SwiftUI]

If i drop `NavigationView` component and set `.ignoresSafeArea()` on `Map` component, i get the toolbar to become translucent but then toolbar takes the full-width of the window, not cutting of at the edge of the sidebar. With the code like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(...)

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Sidebar()
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        .navigationTitle("New York, NY")
    }
}
```

I get the following result. Please note that toolbar is now translucent:

[image: Translucent toolbar without NavigationView]

For the specific purposes, there is no need for `NavigationView` in the app since there is no navigation. I'm using it purely to achieve the correct look for the sidebar and toolbar combination which i've been unable to reproduce without `NavigationView`.

So, the question is whether it is possible to get `NavigationView` to use in-window blending mode or replace it altogether (but with the desired look of similar to what we have in Maps.app).